# According to the Rambam, how do you shake the lulav?

Tags: rambam, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

How do you shake the arba minim according to the Rambam?

Answer (score 4):

From his Laws of *Lulav*, chapter 7:

> ויוליך ויביא ויעלה ויוריד וינענע הלולב שלש פעמים בכל רוח ורוח. כיצד מוליך ומנענע ראש הלולב שלש פעמים ומביא ומנענע ראש הלולב שלש פעמים וכן בעליה וירידה
>
> and he should move it to and fro and up and down, and shake it three times in each direction. How? He moves it to and shakes the tip of the *lulav* three times, and moves it fro and shakes the tip of the *lulav* three times; and the same for up and down.